# What is the relationship between addresses and stake addresses?

Tags: address

Can anyone tell me if an address can change its stake address? If so when does this happen?

Is there a good place to read about how the addresses and the stake address are related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the Shelley address contains the staking address inside (delegation part), so it is not possible to change it. But they are other types of addresses.

One of the best resources to learn about Cardano's addresses is [CIP19: Cardano Addresses](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0019/CIP-0019.md).

Answer (score 1):

So, technically yes, that is possible. For example the stake part of an address can be changed and then funds sent to that address will continue to be staked in the original wallet (the original wallet still gets the stake rewards). That is how staking will be enabled while funds are in a smart contract. Andrew Westberg has a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjPf_b9UQNs) on it (he really should be answering this question).

Comment: I do not think you could be staking and use the funds in a contract (I think you mean a mangled address) as the staking within the contact will be managed by the script output.

Comment: I can't really argue because I'm not exactly sure on how it works. But I know the plan is to enable staking while your ADA is in a smart contract. Otherwise the network's security is reduced if a large amount of ADA is moved out of staking wallets and into contracts (like DeFi pools for example).

Comment: Correct, but this is done by staking the smart contact itself. You are also correct the main reason is PoS security.